# Undefined Control Sequence despite \newcommand using tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, undefined

I want to create a new command to do a certain diagram using tikz. The code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\D}[4]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=1.5em,column
    sep=1.5em,minimum width=2em]
          {
            &#1&\\
            #2& &#3\\
            &#4&\\};
           \path[thick]
           (m-1-2) edge (m-2-1)
           edge (m-2-3)
           (m-3-2) edge (m-2-1)
           edge (m-2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\D{a}{b}{c}{d}
\end{document}
```

But I get this message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options 

l.23 \D{a}{b}{c}{d}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: The `&` character has special catcode and this will not work. See, for example, questions on this site that tries to wrap tabular/array/align/matrix in a command.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

As  Symbol 1 mentioned in a comment, this is because of the `&`, but you can use `ampersand replacement=\&` in the `matrix` options, and use `\&`  instead of `&`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\D}[4]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=1.5em,column
    sep=1.5em,minimum width=2em,ampersand replacement=\&]
          {
            \&#1\&\\
            #2\& \&#3\\
            \&#4\&\\};
           \path[thick]
           (m-1-2) edge (m-2-1)
           edge (m-2-3)
           (m-3-2) edge (m-2-1)
           edge (m-2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\D{a}{b}{c}{d}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was about to complain that you were 'stealing' the answer from the comment, but the temporal distance between the comment and your answer was too short for you not posting this independently. So good timing ;)

Comment: @jjdb Symbol 1 only identified the problem, without suggesting the solution directly, though I wouldn't be the least bit surprised if (s)he knows about `ampersand replacement` as well. I saw the comment before I posted, but I think I had the code ready at that time.

Comment: Yes I thought so. It was really a close race. I watched cheerfully ;) and upvoted your answer… oh I forgot to upvote the comment. I'll do it immediately…

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast and precise answer. Thanks to @Symbol1 as well.